# Bars not showing up when plotting a stack bar chart

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart in R. I I have set up what I think is the right way to organize this data shown below. I am using the following data frame (df_long):

```
>Sample                 Class       value
>1  MR.EBB           SubsectionV 0.376271587
>2  MR.EFT           SubsectionV 0.214530230
>3  MW.EBB           SubsectionV 0.283043915
>4  MW.EFT           SubsectionV 0.231542000
>5  MM.EBB           SubsectionV 0.173081478
>6  MM.EFT           SubsectionV 0.289146505
>7  MR.EBB             Aquificae 0.158061273
>8  MR.EFT             Aquificae 0.062513166
>9  MW.EBB             Aquificae 0.059306831
>10 MW.EFT             Aquificae 0.056433067
>11 MM.EBB             Aquificae 0.017349597
>12 MM.EFT             Aquificae 0.017775538
>13 MR.EBB             Thermales 0.101253844
>14 MR.EFT             Thermales 0.033099853
>15 MW.EBB             Thermales 0.112873134
>16 MW.EFT             Thermales 0.104786977
>17 MM.EBB             Thermales 0.048495973
>18 MM.EFT             Thermales 0.075336022
>19 MR.EBB      Planctomycetacia 0.080287438
>20 MR.EFT      Planctomycetacia 0.279834632
>21 MW.EBB      Planctomycetacia 0.161093571
>22 MW.EFT      Planctomycetacia 0.171961995
>23 MM.EBB      Planctomycetacia 0.106702984
>24 MM.EFT      Planctomycetacia 0.125403226
>25 MR.EBB           Caldilineae 0.066832269
>26 MR.EFT           Caldilineae 0.028834000
>27 MW.EBB           Caldilineae 0.008431401
>28 MW.EFT           Caldilineae 0.028050109
>29 MM.EBB           Caldilineae 0.192444339
>30 MM.EFT           Caldilineae 0.124495968
>31 MR.EBB          unclassified 0.055713272
>32 MR.EFT          unclassified 0.076732673
>33 MW.EBB          unclassified 0.116173938
>34 MW.EFT          unclassified 0.118857420
>35 MM.EBB          unclassified 0.060575557
>36 MM.EFT          unclassified 0.051008065
>37 MR.EBB   Deltaproteobacteria 0.022208422
>38 MR.EFT   Deltaproteobacteria 0.027122393
>39 MW.EBB   Deltaproteobacteria 0.023285017
>40 MW.EFT   Deltaproteobacteria 0.020091987
>41 MM.EBB   Deltaproteobacteria 0.045239223
>42 MM.EFT   Deltaproteobacteria 0.035215054
>43 MR.EBB            Nitrospira 0.021764845
>44 MR.EFT            Nitrospira 0.040841584
>45 MW.EBB            Nitrospira 0.026729334
>46 MW.EFT            Nitrospira 0.034162430
>47 MM.EBB            Nitrospira 0.015040265
>48 MM.EFT            Nitrospira 0.022547043
>49 MR.EBB            Clostridia 0.020995978
>50 MR.EFT            Clostridia 0.032362545
>51 MW.EBB            Clostridia 0.025114811
>52 MW.EFT            Clostridia 0.020666909
>53 MM.EBB            Clostridia 0.026527712
>54 MM.EFT            Clostridia 0.035282258
>55 MR.EBB Thermodesulfobacteria 0.020877691
>56 MR.EFT Thermodesulfobacteria 0.044607120
>57 MW.EBB Thermodesulfobacteria 0.054104478
>58 MW.EFT Thermodesulfobacteria 0.051228516
>59 MM.EBB Thermodesulfobacteria 0.011724301
>60 MM.EFT Thermodesulfobacteria 0.017137097
>61 MR.EBB           Chloroflexi 0.014401467
>62 MR.EFT           Chloroflexi 0.023857173
>63 MW.EBB           Chloroflexi 0.016647532
>64 MW.EFT           Chloroflexi 0.030137981
>65 MM.EBB           Chloroflexi 0.015810043
>66 MM.EFT           Chloroflexi 0.028091398
>67 MR.EBB       Sphingobacteria 0.013307310
>68 MR.EFT       Sphingobacteria 0.033468506
>69 MW.EBB       Sphingobacteria 0.032146958
>70 MW.EFT       Sphingobacteria 0.035463568
>71 MM.EBB       Sphingobacteria 0.017171956
>72 MM.EFT       Sphingobacteria 0.019354839
>73 MR.EBB        Actinobacteria 0.011592146
>74 MR.EFT        Actinobacteria 0.030071624
>75 MW.EBB        Actinobacteria 0.022172790
>76 MW.EFT        Actinobacteria 0.024358509
>77 MM.EBB        Actinobacteria 0.021435339
>78 MM.EFT        Actinobacteria 0.016431452
>79 MR.EBB         Acidobacteria 0.009226402
>80 MR.EFT         Acidobacteria 0.013455867
>81 MW.EBB         Acidobacteria 0.027985075
>82 MW.EFT         Acidobacteria 0.032074558
>83 MM.EBB         Acidobacteria 0.036949313
>84 MM.EFT         Acidobacteria 0.039784946
>85 MR.EBB                 OTHER 0.027206056
>86 MR.EFT                 OTHER 0.058668633
>87 MW.EBB                 OTHER 0.030891217
>88 MW.EFT                 OTHER 0.040183975
>89 MM.EBB                 OTHER 0.211451919
>90 MM.EFT                 OTHER 0.102990591
```

This is my graph input:

```
>ggplot(df_long, aes(x=Sample, y= value, fill= Class))
> geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

When I try and graph it no bars show up. The plot area is there, and The axis labels are correct but there are no bars at all. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Because you didn't add`+` i.e. `ggplot(df_long, aes(x=Sample, y= value, fill= Class)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We need to use `+`

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x=Sample, y= value, fill= Class)) +
                geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```